# htaccess directive conflicting with https -- 404 not found

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2.4

I have a simple problem (I think).

What my website does **correctly** -- The URL `http://example.com/mypage` uses -> `/var/ww/html/mypage.php`  |  Put simply, it essentially allows removal of the `php` extension from the URL.

What my **intended result** is to do the same thing with `https`.  However I am returning a 404.  So my rewrite condition isn't functioning correctly for `https`, but is functioning correctly for `http`.

Here is the **.htaccess** file:

```
RewriteEngine On

Options -MultiViews

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

With this setup, do I have to specify `%{HTTPS}` ?? Is there something else I am missing?

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference with HTTPS. However... how is SSL configured? If `AllowOverride` is not set in the VirtualHost container for port 443 (your SSL host) then your `.htaccess` file won't be processed?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this two line after "RewriteEngine On"

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]]
```

Hopefully it works. Though this will replace http:// with https://

Comment: Negative - No go  --  Plus, for future reference, "code dropping" is frowned upon ...  Try to explain what your code means and **why** you used it ..

Comment: This doesn't appear to have anything to do with the question?! (You also have an erroneous `]` at the end of the `RewriteRule` directive.)